# "logback-classic" issue: Could not access term classic in package ch.qos.logback

Tags: java, scala, logging, logback

I am using `"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7"` as a dependency (in my scala+sbt project) and using the logger: `val internalLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)`

and I am getting the following error:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Logging.class'.
[error] Could not access term classic in package ch.qos.logback,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Logging.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of ch.qos.logback.
[error] one error found
```

The error is general and unclear. Any ideas where things might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add the jar files.

If you are using **maven** then add the following dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use **gradle**, then add it in dependencies section in `build.gradle` file:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.0.13'
```

### Resource Location:

[Logback configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: I think you missed the part I said I am using sbt (and  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7" as the sbt dependency)

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-module sbt project, the logging dependency was not being properly used by one of the modules. I had to add the dependency to the root module.